# Need clarifying Java stateful bean

Tags: java, web-services

When reading document about stateful and stateless bean in Java, I kind of understand but there is this general case making me confusing:

- I have a web service, it needs in-memory data to process request, and this data is added up to the memory through web service requests, not by loading from database. To make this simple, please think of the web service provides methods to process students' data, but at first, the data of all students in a class need to be put into the memory, assuming that the data is just temporarily so we don't put and load them from any database.
- Assuming at the first step we have 3 clients call to web service to add many students' data into the web service.
- At the second step, each client calls to a web service method, says int getRank(student), this method implementation is just looping through all students' data and check the rank of the inputted student based on his mark on particular subject. And that's all, an integer number will be returned and we do not need to store any client-service related thing so I guess we don't need a stateful bean. However, since after each call to put student data to the service, that data need to be remained in the memory, it seems we have some kind of stateful thing here but I don't know what it is called and is this make the service called stateful web service.

Thank you for any idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like "caching" to me.  You periodically update a chunk of data that resides in memory to save the network latency; it's possible because the chunk is not overly large.

I'd say that any standard caching solution would do.  You just have to be careful when loading the values in to ensure that read operations aren't going on and to make sure that it's an orderly process.  Multiple clients should not have any opportunity to harm anyone else's data.

I would agree - you don't need stateful session beans.  You need caching.

Comment: Thank you. "caching" sounds complex, what if I have a global data collection object and I just add items to that list?

Comment: A cache should be "read mostly" - you read from it a lot more often than you write.  It sounded like your multi-client load operation was periodic and free of writes.  Is that true?  If not, you just have to synchronize during write ops and invalid values from time to time to make sure that no one sees stale data.  Check out products - EhCache and Terracotta are open source.  Coherence is not.    http://www.terracotta.org/

Comment: If the amount of data is not too big, and the performance is the first priority then should I just use a global data collection, instead of cache?

Comment: Unwrapped globals are generally a bad idea.  Whether you write one yourself or use someone else's, what I'm describing is a component that hides what you're calling a global data collection inside.  Why expose a List?  And someone who has spent as much time developing an open source cache as the folks at Terracotta or EhCache probably learned a few things that you don't about how to do it well.  Why not tap into that?  You're right - doing it yourself means fast and one less dependency.  Your call.

Comment: Are you suggesting that your out of the box global collection will perform better under all use cases than a cache that's been on the market for years?  Are you also implying that folks who write caches don't care about performance?  Your thought process is silly.